# ClickHouse Kafka Engine: how to upgrade Kafka consumer version for KafkaEngine

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

How to upgrade the version of Kafka library used by Kafka Engine in ClickHouse?

And, how to know actual version in use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the shared build, you might be able to grab the needed DSO files of librdkafka and replace the old one. Though there is a chance that the ABI is incompatible as librdkafka hasn't even a stable release yet. Otherwise, just rebuild ClickHouse with the librdkafka you need.

As for looking up the version of current librdkafka, here is one way,

```
select * from system.build_options
```

get the `VERSION_GITHASH` and do

```
git ls-tree <VERSION_GITHASH> contrib/librdkafka
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record, CH latest has `0.11.4` (at the time of writing this comment). However master `librdkafka` seems to have support for `zstandard`, which is a `2.1` feature I was looking for.